# Difference of top two values while GROUP BY

Tags: postgresql, group-by

Suppose I have the following SQL Table:

```
id | score
------------
1  |  4433
1  |  678
1  |  1230
1  |  414
5  |  8899
5  |  123
6  |  2345
6  |  567
6  |  2323
```

Now I wanted to do a `GROUP BY id` operation wherein the `score` column would be modified as follows: take the absolute difference between the top two highest scores for each `id`.

For example, the response for the above query should be:

```
id  |  score
------------
1   |  3203
5   |  8776
6   |  22
```

How can I perform this query in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` along with pivoting logic we can try:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY score DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id,
       ABS(MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) -
               MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE rn = 2)) AS score
FROM cte
GROUP BY id;
```

### Demo

Comment: Thanks a lot! That would answer the asked question but when I try on my database, it is giving NULL values because I have another column called `name` and I also want two more columns now: the first person's name and the second person's name among whom the difference was taken (for each id - the id column is actually called `year`).  How can I also include them? Should I modify the question?

Comment: You should ask a new question because what you are describing is fairly different than what you asked above (and what I answered).  Stack Overflow is not an ongoing blog site where you get to keep changing your question.